# Upload file with formspree

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to allow users on my website to upload an image with a form.
I have been using formspree (https://formspree.io/)
I receive the name of the image but no image attached to the email.

I'm using:

```
<label>
    Upload Photo
    <input type="file" name="uploadField" />
</label>
```

Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Formspree currently doesn't support file inputs, but Formsprees FAQ has this advice:

> For almost zero work and cheap (or free) prices you can integrate external file upload services into a Formspree form. [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com/) is one example. If you just create an account and include their widget:

```
<!-- The best place for this one is your <HEAD> tag -->
<script>UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY = "demopublickey";</script>
<script 
src="https://ucarecdn.com/libs/widget/3.x/uploadcare.full.min.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- This is where the widget will be. Don't forget the name attribute! -->
<input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="my_file" />
```

> Per [their documentation](https://uploadcare.com/quick_start/), you can use that  inside the Formspree form and receive the URL of the document in your email address.

Source: https://help.formspree.io/articles/6199-how-to-do-file-uploads-with-formspree

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is your `enctype` isn't defined. Here's an example using a basic HTML form (you'll need some PHP/server side code to process the file):

```
<form action="your_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Image: <input type="file" name="uploadField" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott
I hadn't defined enctype but that doesn't seem to fix it. Formspree doesn't require any PHP to process - might have to look at doing it that way if I can't get this to work though.

Comment: The enctype is needed if you're uploading a file. If formspree doesn't require a script then just remove the action value from my example above. If that doesn't work, probably best to contact Formspree